# Word that means to fit together in a limited space?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

So I work in delivery, and I am trying to describe the act (verb I guess) of fitting parcels in the back of a van in the most efficient way possible. I thought about using the word "Tessellation" in a verb like way "We tessellated the packages as best we could". I also thought about using the classic "We Tetrised... tetrissed?" the packages as best we could. Does anyone know a good word I can use?

Comment: I am thinking along the lines of *compact*, *close-packed*, and *pack down*.

Comment: When I used to work on farms in the school holidays we used to efficiently load hay bales on to a trailer. We called it 'stacking'.

Answer (score 2):

**Tetris** can be indeed used as a verb for this meaning. It is not in the big dictionaries yet but it has a definition in *[urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tetris)* and *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tetris)*. Additionally, *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tetris-video-game-verb)* has an article about *tetris* being used as a verb. Here is a relevant excerpt:

> The game known as *Tetris* has pervaded the culture to such an extent that it has inspired occasional, creative use of *Tetris* as a verb, one meaning something along the lines of **"to arrange the parts of (something) to fit efficiently within a limited space"**:
>
> The use of *Tetris* as a verb is still too rare for dictionary entry, but it has nonetheless become an option as a word for clever spatial arrangement. And you can even prefix *Tetris* if you need a verb for removing something from said configuration:
>
> *I'd gone grocery shopping the day before, and the crowded kitchen shelves were Tetrised with Betty's favorites: mac and cheese, Cheerios, cinnamon grahams. 
>
>   Amy Shearn, The Mermaid of Brooklyn, 2013*
>
> <sub>*https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tetris-video-game-verb*</sub>

<sub><sup>(emphasis mine, italicized the example)</sup></sub>

Comment: You can consider _arrange_ as a common verb but it lacks the precise meaning. You might need to add additional wording or an adverb.

Comment: 'We're not able to include it in the dictionary, but we can give a long spiel about it and you can use it' [paraphrased] disinclines me to use M-W.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sardine as a verb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sardine) and that will probably match the definition you’re going for. “We sardined the packages into the truck”